# EF Query not working with MySql but working fine using SqlServer

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Hi i have recently migrated my project to MySql from SqlServer 2014, and many of the EF queries stops working, and giving different different error. Right now i am struggling with:

```
Var allData = (from p in dbObj.servicewiserevenues
                           where p.pdate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && p.pdate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                           group p by p.tbservice.tbcountry.CountryName into grp
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       N = grp.Key,
                                       R = grp.Sum(a => a.total_revenue / a.tbservice.tbcountry.CountryCurrencyConversionRate)
                                   }).AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(p => new
                                  {
                                      Name = p.N,
                                      Revenue=p.R
                                      //Revenue =Convert.ToDouble(p.R).ToString("#,#",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
                                  }).OrderBy(z => z.Name).ToList();
```

This query is perfectly working when used with SqlServer but now giving error with MySql.

Error is:

> Unknown column 'Distinct1.CountryName' in 'where clause' Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown
>   column 'Distinct1.CountryName' in 'where clause'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 189:        { Line 190:            var allData = default(object);
>   Line 191:            allData = (from p in dbObj.servicewiserevenues
>   Line 192:                       where p.pdate.Month ==
>   DateTime.Now.Month && p.pdate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year Line 193:
>   group p by p.tbservice.tbcountry.CountryName into grp
>
> Source File: F:\Guri_Projects\DM\DM\Controllers\HomeController.cs
>   Line: 191

Comment: What is the column name in your table? I know that SQL server is case-insensitive, my guess would be that MySQL is case-sensitive. Check the [ColumnName] attribute on yourCountryName property. Is it *exactly* the same as the column name in your db?

Comment: Column name is accurate and already checked. Even these are from intellisense help and considered the original names which is already in database.

Comment: I give up then. Sorry. Probably worth trying select "CountryName" from country-table as a direct query to see what you get. You could try grabbing the EF query as a string and putting it into a MySQL query window. Does it break with the same error? If you can fix it and get it to work in the query window without involving EF this would at least give you a clue. Bon chance ... :-)